# Error al ver el precio del pedido

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Tengo este código en el que he realizado un catalogo de pedido en un menu.
Al parecer todo funciona correctamente hasta que llego al punto de ver pedido y me lanza este error.

```
1. Añadir producto al catálogo
2. Listado de productos
3. Crear un pedido nuevo
4. Ver pedido  
5. Salir

4

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Act3.Comanda.calcularPreu(Comanda.java:64)
    at Act3.Comanda.toString(Comanda.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3352)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:807)
    at Act3.LlistaComandes.showComandes(LlistaComandes.java:25)
    at Act3.Empresa.showComandes(Empresa.java:109)
    at Act3.Menu.menu(Menu.java:51)
    at Act3.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Este es mi codigo es un tanto extenso pido disculpas es que no logro encontrar donde está el error.

**Main**

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Menu menu = new Menu();

            menu.menu();

        }

    }
```

**Menu**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    private Empresa empresa;

    private Scanner scanner;

    private final int OP_ANADIR_PRODUCTO = 1;
    private final int OP_VER_CATALOGO = 2;
    private final int OP_CREAR_COMANDA = 3;
    private final int OP_VER_COMANDA = 4;
    private final int OP_EXIT = 10;

    public Menu() {

        this.empresa = new Empresa();
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    private int eleccionMenu(){

        System.out.println(OP_ANADIR_PRODUCTO + ". Añadir producto al catálogo");
        System.out.println(OP_VER_CATALOGO + ". Listado de productos");
        System.out.println(OP_CREAR_COMANDA + ". Crear un pedido nuevo");
        System.out.println(OP_VER_COMANDA + ". Ver pedido");
        System.out.println(OP_EXIT + ". Salir");

        return scanner.nextInt();

    }

    public void menu(){

        int opcion;

        do {

            opcion = eleccionMenu();

            if (opcion == OP_ANADIR_PRODUCTO) {
                empresa.newProducto();
            } else if (opcion == OP_VER_CATALOGO) {
                empresa.showCatalogo();
            } else if (opcion == OP_CREAR_COMANDA) {
                empresa.newComanda();
            } else if (opcion == OP_VER_COMANDA) {
                empresa.showComandes();
            }

        } while (opcion != OP_EXIT);

    }

}
```

**Producto**

```
public class Producte {

    private int codi;

    private String nom;

    private float preu;

    private int descompte;

    private int iva;

    public Producte(int codi, String nom, float preu, int descompte, int iva) {
        this.codi = codi;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.preu = preu;
        this.descompte = descompte;
        this.iva = iva;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {

        this.nom = nom;

    }

    public void setCodi(int codi) {

        this.codi = codi;

    }

    public void setDescompte(int descompte) {

        this.descompte = descompte;

    }

    public void setIva(int iva) {

        this.iva = iva;

    }

    public void setPreu(float preu) {

        this.preu = preu;

    }

    public int getCodi() {

        return codi;

    }

    public float getPvp(){

        return  ((preu * iva) / 100) - ((preu * descompte) / 100);

     }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  codi +
                ". Nom: " + nom +
                "---> " + preu + "€\n\n";
    }
}
```

**Lista de comandas**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LlistaComandes {

    private ArrayList<Comanda> llistaComandes;

    public LlistaComandes() {

        this.llistaComandes = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void addComanda(Comanda comanda){

        llistaComandes.add(comanda);

    }

    public void showComandes(){

        for (int i = 0; i < llistaComandes.size(); i++) {

            System.out.print(llistaComandes.get(i));

        }
    }

}
```

**Empresa**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Empresa {

    private Scanner scanner;

    private CatalogoProductos catalogoProductos;

    private LlistaComandes llistaComandes;

    public Empresa() {

        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.catalogoProductos = new CatalogoProductos();
        this.llistaComandes = new LlistaComandes();

    }

    public void newProducto(){

        System.out.println("Introduce el código del producto");
        int codigo = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del producto");
        String nombre = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Introduce el precio del producto");
        float precio = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Introduce el descuento del producto");
        int descuento = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduce el IVA del producto");
        int iva = scanner.nextInt();

        Producte newProducte = new Producte(codigo, nombre, precio, descuento, iva);

        catalogoProductos.addProducto(newProducte);

    }

    public void removeProductoEmpresa(){

        catalogoProductos.showCatalogo();

        System.out.println("Introduce el código del producto que deseas eliminar");
        int codigo = scanner.nextInt();

        Producte producte = catalogoProductos.getProducteCatalogo(codigo);

        catalogoProductos.removeProducto(producte);

    }

    public void modProducto(){

        catalogoProductos.showCatalogo();

        System.out.println("Introduce el código del producto que deseas modificar");
        int codigo = scanner.nextInt();

        Producte producte = catalogoProductos.getProducteCatalogo(codigo);

    }

    public void showCatalogo(){

        catalogoProductos.showCatalogo();

    }

    public void newComanda(){

        System.out.println("Introduce el código de la comanda");
        int codigo = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del cliente");
        String cliente = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Introduce la fecha (dd/mm/yyyy)");
        String fecha = scanner.next();

        Comanda comanda = new Comanda(codigo, fecha, cliente);

        int opcion;

        catalogoProductos.showCatalogo();

        do {

            System.out.println("Introduce el código del producto que deseas añadir (0 para salir)");
            opcion = scanner.nextInt();

            Producte producte = catalogoProductos.getProducteCatalogo(opcion);

            comanda.addProducte(producte);

        } while (opcion != 0);

        llistaComandes.addComanda(comanda);

    }

    public void showComandes(){

        llistaComandes.showComandes();

    }
}
```

**Comanda**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Comanda {

    private int codi;

    private ArrayList<Producte> productes;

    private String fecha;

    private String nomClient;

    public Comanda(int codi, String fecha, String nomClient) {

        this.codi = codi;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.nomClient = nomClient;
        this.productes = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void addProducte(Producte producte){

        productes.add(producte);

    }

    public Producte getProducteComanda(int codi){

        for (int i = 0; i < productes.size(); i++){

            Producte producte = productes.get(i);

            if (producte.getCodi() == codi){

                return producte;

            }

        }

        return null;

    }

    private void showProductes(){

        for (int i = 0; i < productes.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(productes.get(i));

        }

    }

    private float calcularPreu(){

        float preu = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < productes.size(); i++){

            preu += productes.get(i).getPvp();

        }

        return preu;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return codi + ":\n" +
                "Preu: " + calcularPreu() + "€";
    }
}
```

**Cliente**

```
public class Client {

    private String nom;

    public Client(String nom) {

        this.nom = nom;

    }
}
```

**Catalogo de productos**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatalogoProductos {

    private ArrayList<Producte> catalogoProductos;

    public CatalogoProductos() {

        this.catalogoProductos = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void addProducto(Producte producte){

        catalogoProductos.add(producte);

    }

    public void  removeProducto(Producte producte){

        catalogoProductos.remove(producte);

    }

    public Producte getProducteCatalogo(int codi){

        for (int i = 0; i < catalogoProductos.size(); i++){

            Producte producte = catalogoProductos.get(i);

            if (producte.getCodi() == codi){

                return producte;

            }

        }

        return null;

    }

    public void showCatalogo(){

        for (int i = 0; i < catalogoProductos.size(); i++){

            System.out.print(catalogoProductos.get(i));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se provoca cuando tratas de llamar getPvp() en una instancia con valor null que esta almacenada en el ArrayList productes, puedes realizar la validación para evitar este error:

```
private float calcularPreu(){

    float preu = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < productes.size(); i++){
        if(productes.get(i) == null){
           // productes ES NULL");
        }else{
            preu += productes.get(i).getPvp();
        }

    }

    return preu;

}
```

**Pero analizando tu código, el valor null que insertas en el ArrayList `productes` se realiza en esta sección del código de tu clase `Empresa`, por lo cual te recomiendo validar cuando sales y no fue encontrado algùn producto**:

```
  ...
  ...
  do {

        System.out.println("Introduce el código del producto que deseas añadir (0 para salir)");
        opcion = scanner.nextInt();

        Producte producte = catalogoProductos.getProducteCatalogo(opcion);

        //ERROR!!! En ocasiones se inserta un elemento vacío.
        //comanda.addProducte(producte);

        //* Validar!
        if(producte != null){ //Se encontro producto.
              comanda.addProducte(producte);
        }else{
             //No se encontro producto.;
        }

    } while (opcion != 0);
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! ya no sale el error, tan solo era añadir la comprobación ya entiendo la no detectar correctamente el resultado daba error y al comprobarlo si es una cosa dará el resultado correcto y sino mostrara que no hay productos

Comment: Excelente @azucarilla , saludos!